# iPad zoom separates website divs

Tags: javascript, ipad, zooming, scale

I am having an issue on my website I am building when viewing on an iPad or iPhone.

The header of the page is position:fixed; to the top. Whilst the rest of the website scrolls down in a container div.

Basically when i view on the iPad, and pinch to zoom. The header element zoom and moves to the right, and the scrollable content moves left and also enlarges so i end up with as website that is in two sections?

I have attempted to use the min-width:1024 css and user-scalable=0 but neither work. The user-scalable stops it from being zoomed but then when it rotated to portrait from landscape, the website retains the width at landscape as it rotates, so then the website is too wide for the screen.

Hope I have explained this well enough.

I have tried some javascript which I got from this website but that completely scrambles the whole website as it rotates...

the code I tried to use is below:

...html header...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

...javscript...

```
var checkOrientation;
checkOrientation = function() {
  var viewport;
  viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
  if (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90) {
    return viewport.setAttribute("content", "width:device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-    scalable=0");
  } else {
    return viewport.setAttribute("content", "width:device-width, initial-scale=0.6, user-    scalable=0");
  }
};
window.onorientationchange = function() {
  return checkOrientation();
};
checkOrientation();
```

Thank you in advance